# PHP C# MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I try to do encrypt (with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 Cipher CBC) in PHP and C#, but the output does not match.

```
key = '1234567812345678';
iv = '1234567812345678';
```

PHP:

```
function Encrypt($data, $key, $iv) {
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_encode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
}
```

C#:

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key, string iv)
{
    byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);
    byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        symmetricKey.KeySize = 128;
        symmetricKey.BlockSize = 128;
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: Use a proper padding such as PKCS#5/PKCS#7, because this zero padding might corrupt your plaintext if it has trailing 0x00 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the input on the iv and padding, Will look that in phase 2. For time being, let's assume I use a specified IV and padding zeroes. I have same procedure working in Delphi and it is aligned (or output the same) as php. But not the c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problems lies within your PHP code.

The `mcrypt_encrypt` function expects the data (which needs to be encoded) to be in plaintext format, so you don't need an additional `base64_encode` since you are working with strings. The same way you pass the `key` and the `iv` to the function, you should hand your `data` variable to it. *(untested)*

```
function Encrypt($data, $key, $iv) {
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
}
```

Let me know your progress, so that I can help you with this in the future if anything doesn't work :)

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I have other same procedure in delphi and it outputs the same as PHP, but not c#. Not sure what is wrong there.

Comment: Could you update your question with your delphi procedure?

Comment: I just tested without base64_encode and apparently it IS the problem. It is solved. Thanks so much.